# Why are "de" and "des" both ok in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaire, articles

I was reading a podcast text and found this sentence:

> ça peut être des attentats, c'est-à-dire des attentats terroristes.

and then I threw the English version of it into Google Translate and got this in return:

> ça peut être des attentats, c'est-à-dire d'attentats terroristes.

Does this mean both "de" and "des" here are ok (if so, why?) or is one of these two sentences a wrong one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second sentence is incorrect, *des* is required here.

A reason that might explain why the translator was mistaken is that *peut être* and *peut s'agir* are synonymous but the latter use *de*:

> Il peut s'agir d'attentats, c'est à dire d'attentats terroristes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just know the translator can't really be trusted.